# Django makes too many processes (on fastCGI)

Tags: django, django-views, fastcgi

I have a Django app with fastCGI.

The following view starts lots of proccesses named **"/usr/bin/python index.fcgi"**. They suddenly appear and just stay there forever.

```
def serveMusicFile(request,filename):
    from django.conf import settings
    file = open('/my/private/file/location/'+filename)
    response = HttpResponse(file.read(), mimetype="audio/mpeg")
    response['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize('/my/private/file/location/'+filename)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename='+filename
    return response
```

**So,** why does Django/fastCGI start this proccess? How can I stop them being pilled?

Comment: I edited the question and removed unneccesary parts to make it moke readable... please help!

Comment: Do you use any web-server? Does these processes appear in dev mode?

Comment: I have only one mode (no production yet..). And I didn't understand your question - I'm on a shared server of a hosting company with apache and fastCGI. Does that answer your question?